# "No supported shared memory caching support was found when configuring opcache" when building the latest PHP 8.0.6+ on OS X 11.3.1

Tags: php, macos, compiler-errors, llvm, macos-big-sur

I am attempting to run `./configure --with-iconv=/usr/local/opt/libiconv` to build the latest PHP from the php-src/php-src Github repo on OSX using the LLVM-11 Clang Compiler (PHP 8.0.6 + latest commits on the Master branch). However, the configuration script breaks at:

```html
checking whether to enable Zend OPcache support... yes
checking whether to enable copying PHP CODE pages into HUGE PAGES... yes
checking whether to enable JIT... yes
checking for capstone >= 3.0.0... yes
checking for opagent in default path... not found
checking for mprotect... yes
checking for sysvipc shared memory support... no
checking for mmap() using MAP_ANON shared memory support... no
checking for shm_open in -lrt... no
checking for __shm_open in -lrt... no
checking for shm_open in -lroot... no
checking for __shm_open in -lroot... no
checking for mmap() using shm_open() shared memory support... no
configure: error: No supported shared memory caching support was found when configuring opcache. Check config.log for any errors or missing dependencies.
```

Here are the environment flags I export before running the configuration script:

```html
# Compiler Flags
export CC=/opt/local/libexec/llvm-11/bin/clang
export LD=/opt/local/libexec/llvm-11/bin/ld
export CPP=/opt/local/libexec/llvm-11/bin/clang-cpp
export CXX=/opt/local/libexec/llvm-11/bin/clang++
export CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.1.0/bin/g++-11
export OBJCXX=/opt/local/libexec/llvm-11/bin/clang
export CFLAGS='-Ofast -arch x86_64 -I/opt/local/include -I/usr/local/include'
export CPATH='/opt/local/include'
export CPPFLAGS='-I/opt/local/libexec/llvm-11/include -I/opt/local/libexec/llvm-11/include/c++/v1/ -Ofast -isystem/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include -I/usr/local/include'
export CXXFLAGS='-I/opt/local/libexec/llvm-11/include -I/opt/local/libexec/llvm-11/include/c++/v1/ -Ofast -arch x86_64 -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include'
export F90FLAGS='-Ofast -m64'
export FCFLAGS='-Ofast -m64'
export FFLAGS='-Ofast -m64'
export INSTALL='/usr/bin/install -c'
export LDFLAGS='-L/opt/local/libexec/llvm-11/lib -Wl,-rpath,/opt/local/libexec/llvm-11/lib -L/opt/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L/opt/lib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -arch x86_64'
export OBJCXXFLAGS='-Ofast -arch x86_64'

# PHP Flags
export PHP_BUILD_ZTS_ENABLE=on
export PHP_BUILD_XDEBUG_ENABLE=on
export PHP_BUILD_EXTRA_MAKE_ARGUMENTS=-j"$(getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN)"
export PHP_BUILD_TMPDIR=~/Tools/Sources/php
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=""
for pkg in openssl icu4c libxml2; do
    PKG_CONFIG_PATH="${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}:$(brew --prefix $pkg)/lib/pkgconfig"
done
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}"

# Library PATHs
export DEVELOPER_DIR='/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools'
export LIBRARY_PATH='/opt/local/lib'
```

LLVM-11 was built using MacPorts. This does not happen on the Homebrew Apple Clang 12 compiler, but that one does not find all the needed library paths. I would greatly appreciate any ideas to what could be going on. `./configure --disable-opcache` does run successfully, but I wish to have the OPCache module in my installation.